# Editing individual vertices in unwrapped UV Map?

Tags: uv

I'm very new to Blender and have been able to get by with video tutorials thus far but this one issue has me a little stumped.
While unwrapping, the vertices by the edge of the seam have become distorted and no longer fit the provided UV map and are stretching and cutting off parts the texture.  How can I edit and re-align the individual effected vertices on the UV map to fit the original texture properly and prevent stretching?  I'm using 2.79 by the way (can't update further right now).
[image: Here are some pics of the issue]

[image]

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help!